# Exception - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: asp.net

```
  private void LoadChartData(DataTable initialDataSource)
    {
        try
        {
         for (int i = 1; i < initialDataSource.Columns.Count; i++)
         {
            Series series = new Series();
            foreach (DataRow dr in initialDataSource.Rows)
            {
                **int y = (int)dr[i];**
                series.Points.AddXY(dr["Data"].ToString(), y);
            }
            Chart1.Series.Add(series);
         }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Above is my code that cause the exception specified cast is not valid, Bold font shows where it cause, Pls suggest me

Comment: What data is inside this column? If it is empty or not an integer the cast can easily fail

Comment: may be the dr[i] is null. also use Convert.ToInt32() insteaed of that type of casting